# Finding a metric such that $\Phi$ becomes a contraction

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, fixed-point-theorems

Let
$$
f:\:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R};\\
\Phi: \mathcal{F}([0,1], \mathbb{R})
\rightarrow \mathcal{F}([0,1], \mathbb{R}),\\
f\mapsto\Phi(f):=Φf := \left(x\mapsto\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l@{\quad:\quad}l}
\frac{1}{2}f(3x) & 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{2}f(1) & \frac{1}{3} \le x \le \frac{2}{3} \\
\frac{1}{2}f(3(x-\frac{2}{3}))+\frac{1}{2}f(1) & \frac{2}{3} \le x \le 1
\end{array}\right.\right)
$$
Where $\mathcal{F}(A, B)$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$.

Since the actual assignment is to show that $(\Phi^n(\mathrm{id}))_n$ converges uniformly to a continuous function $g$, I have to find a metric $d$ such that $Φ$ becomes a contraction, or equivalently:
$$∃k\in[0,1):\: ∀f,g\in\mathcal{F}([0,1],\mathbb{R}): d(Φf,Φg)≤k\:d(f,g)$$.

I assumed that this should be the case for the uniform norm, so i looked at $[0,1]=[0,\frac{1}{3}]\cup[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]\cup[\frac{2}{3},1]:=A\cup B\cup C$ separately:

$$
{∥Φf-Φg∥}_A
= \sup\left\{\frac{1}{2}|f(3x)-g(3x)|,\:x\in A\right\}
= \frac{1}{2}\sup\left\{|f(y)-g(y)|,\:y\in [0,1]\right\}
= \frac{1}{2}{∥f-g∥}
$$

$$
{∥Φf-Φg∥}_B
= \sup\left\{\frac{1}{2}|f(1)-g(1)|,\:x\in B\right\}
= \frac{1}{2}{∥f-g∥_{\{1\}}}
≤ \frac{1}{2}{∥f-g∥}
$$

$$
{∥Φf-Φg∥}_C
= \sup\left\{\frac{1}{2}|f(3(x-\frac{2}{3}))-g(3(x-\frac{2}{3}))+f(1)-g(1)|,\:x\in C\right\}
= \frac{1}{2}\sup\left\{|f(y)-g(y)+f(1)-g(1)|,\:y\in [0,1]\right\}
≤ \frac{1}{2}\sup\left\{|f(y)-g(y)|+|f(1)-g(1)|,\:y\in [0,1]\right\}
= \frac{1}{2}(∥f-g∥ + ∥f-g∥_{\{1\}})
≤ {∥f-g∥}
$$

but the last part does not fit into what I'm trying to show, since $k$ is supposed to be $≤1$.

as far as I can see, there are two possibilities:

1. The upper estimation of the limit was too big, there is a smaller one leading to a valid $k$.
2. The uniform norm does *not* make $Φ$ a contraction, I have to find another metric.

Which one of these possibilities holds? If it is the latter, what other metric should I seek for?

Comment: You don't need to find a metric in which $\Phi$ becomes a contraction - in fact, you cannot find such a metric, since $\Phi$ has more than one fixed point. Just look at the sequence $\Phi^n(\operatorname{id})$. Explicitly compute the first few terms to see what happens, and then show that the sequence converges uniformly.

Comment: I know what $Φ^n(\mathrm{id})$ looks like (actually, I visualized it here: https://github.com/lukasjuhrich/ipy/blob/master/Phi_operator_plot.ipynb )
But now I am confused, since the assignment says “Find a suitable complete metric space, for which you can apply the Banach fixed-point theorem on Φ”.
Does that mean I shall look what these other fixed points are (which I don't know at the moment), and just consider a subset of $\mathcal{F}([0,1],ℝ)$?

Comment: On a suitable subspace (not linear subspace) of $\mathcal{F}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, you can apparently find a metric such that $\Phi$ becomes a contraction. Not on the whole space, since $\Phi$ has more than one fixed point there ($f\equiv 0$ is easily seen to be one). Well, $\Phi$ is linear, so if $f$ is a fixed point, so is $c\cdot f$ for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$. I would try with something like the space of (continuous?) monotonic functions with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Not sure whether that is a small enough subspace, but worth looking at. (And just to mention it: Cantor function.)

Comment: Hm, although $f:\:x\mapsto 0$ was appearent, I did not think of the linearity.
I know this is the cantor function as I have been told, thanks for the remark anyway. I will try to find a proper subset. Thanks a lot at first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ *such that* $f(1)=1$. Then $X$ is complete in the uniform norm, the identity function is in $X$, and it's easy to show that $\Phi$ is a strict contraction on $X$.